# sftp avoid exit when file is not found

Tags: bash, sftp

I have this script:

```
filePattern='sor.log*'
filePattern2='sor.SOR.log*'
myLocation=/opt/tradertools/omer
clientLocation=/opt/tradertools/omer/sor/from
clientName=vmonitorlmpa
clientUser=root
clientPass=triltest

export SSHPASS=$clientPass

sshpass -e sftp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oBatchMode=no -b - $clientUser@$clientName << !

    get $clientLocation/$filePattern2 $myLocation
    get $clientLocation/$filePattern $myLocation

   bye
!
```

But if `filepattern2` isn't found, it will exit. How do I avoid using two SFTP connections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting the [`sftp` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp):

> `sftp` will abort if any of the following commands fail: `get`, `put`, `reget`, `reput`, `rename`, `ln`, `rm`, `mkdir`, `chdir`, `ls`, `lchdir`, `chmod`, `chown`, `chgrp`, `lpwd`, `df`, `symlink`, and `lmkdir`.
>
> Termination on error can be suppressed on a command by command basis **by prefixing the command with a `-` character** (for example, `-rm /tmp/blah*`).

So use:

```
-get $clientLocation/$filePattern2 $myLocation
```